# How to read alternative tags in xml using java?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have xml file

```
<A>
   <A1>
      <A2>Hi</A2>
   </A1>
<A>
<B>
   <B1></B1>
   <B2>100</B2>
</B>
<A>
   <A1>
      <A2>Hello</A2>
   </A1>
<A>
<B>
   <B1>1000</B1>
   <B2></B2>
</B>
```

likewise this goes more than 10 blocks. Now my java code able to read one by one that is first reads all  after that reads  tag.

Code:

```
public class XMLParse {
    static Document doc;
 public static void main(String argv[]) {
  try {
  File file = new File("/home/dev042/Desktop/xxx.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  doc = db.parse(file);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("A");
  System.out.println("Information of all Balence Sheet");
 int count = nodeLst.getLength();
 String name;
  for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

    Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

    if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
      NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("A1");
      for(int i =0; i < fstNmElmntLst.getLength(); i++ )
      {
          Node lst = fstNmElmntLst.item(i);
          if(lst.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
          {
              Element fsttravel = (Element) lst;
              NodeList secNmElt = fsttravel.getElementsByTagName("*");
               name = secNmElt.item(0).getTextContent();
               System.out.println("Name : "  + name);
          }
      }
    }

  }
}
   catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  String amt;
  double amount;
  NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("B");
   int coun = nodeLst.getLength();
  for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {
      Node secNode = nodeLst.item(s);

     if (secNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
       try
              {
                Element amtval = (Element) secNode;
                NodeList secval = amtval.getElementsByTagName("B1");
                amt = secval.item(0).getTextContent();
                //amount = Double.parseDouble(amt);
                System.out.println("SubAmt :" + amt);

                NodeList lstNmElmntLst = amtval.getElementsByTagName("B2");
                amt = lstNmElmntLst.item(0).getTextContent();
                System.out.println("MainAmt : " +amt);
              }
              catch(Exception ex){
                  ex.printStackTrace();
             }
     }
  }

 }
}
```

current output:

```
Hi
Hello
100
1000
```

I want to read the tags alternatively. then only i can able map the values. How can i read these tags alternatively. output should be like this

```
Hi 100
Hello 1000
```

Kindly help me out of it. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post your current code. How are you parsing the XML?

Comment: Use a DOM parser instead of SAX Parser

Comment: I am not aware of that.. could you please explain in detail..

Comment: Please don't torture yourself with the DOM API! Switch to JDOM, you'll see how much simpler it is, and the resulting code is way simpler.

Comment: I have gone through it and done it.. thank a lot..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to filter only  tags so that your parser will fetch only  tags.For this you can use `XPath`.This is an examples here:

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/java-xpath.shtml